# Priority method call order

Tags: java

I've came across an interesting thing in here. That is not a problem I'm just curious about the priority order. Lets go to the code:

I have these two methods on the same class:

```
1-    public void method1(String a, String...b){
2-        System.out.println(a + "===" + b[0]);
3-    }
4- 
5-    public void method1(String a, String b){
6-        method1(a, b);
7-    }
8-
9-    public static void main(String[] args) {
10-       Teste t = new Teste();
11-       t.method1("a", "b");
12-   }
```

Running the tests here I see that the call to the `method1` on line 11 will call the `method1` defined on line 5 then it will do a self-call, therefore a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. My question is regarding the priority order call for theese methods, as `method1` on line 1 receives an `String, String[]` and `method1` on line 5 receives an `String, String` in theory they receive the same parameters if I want to pass just one string on the second parameter to both methods.

I know that on this scenario to call specific the method on line 1 with just one string as second parameter I would have to do `method1("someString", new String[]{"someString"});`

I would like to know if is there is any explanation (or docs) to this priority order call. That says something like:

"In a method definition with same parameters with one of the methods receiving an object and the other an array of the same object if you pass just one parameter, the method that will execute it will be the one that receives just one object instead the one that receive the array for that object"

Comment: What additional benefit does your second version of `method1` provide?

Comment: Nothing... It was just for curiosity. As I said on the question.

Comment: Since *varagrs* were introduced in the language only with Java 1.5 they are being taken into consideration by the method resolution mechanism after all other potentially applicable *non-varagrs* methods (that was done to preserve the existing behavior). Also, regarding the difference between two flavors of `method1()`, the second one doesn't wrap its arguments with an array (that's a minor advantage). For instance, method call `method1("fooBar");` would be mapped by the compiler to the varargs flavor of the method and an empty array would be allocated in memory (sorry commenting old question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer can be found in [15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> There may be more than one such method, in which case the most
>   specific one is chosen. The descriptor (signature plus return type) of
>   the most specific method is one used at run time to perform the method
>   dispatch.

Go through it and see the [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) for better explanation.

Comment: Great. Thats exactly what I was trying to find. Thanks. As soon as I can accept this I will.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm glad it helped :) Referring to the official docs and to the JLS is the best thing someone can do.